# Ввод множества c++

Tags: c++

Есть задача:
"Во входной строке записана последовательность чисел через пробел. Для каждого числа выведите слово YES (в отдельной строке), если это число ранее встречалось в последовательности или NO, если не встречалось"
Вопрос: Вводится неопределенное кол-во чисел, а как ввести это неопределенное кол-во чисел(вводить нужно в множество "set")
Буду благодарен)

Comment: Строка ведь одна! просто берите из нее числа, пока она не кончится. Скажем, с помощью `istringstream`.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы читаете из терминала, то можно сделать, как сказал Harry. Читаем строку, превращаем её в поток и читаем. Реализация:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string s;
    set <int> S;
    int n = 0;
    getline(cin, s);
    istringstream i(s);
    while (i >> n)
        if (S.count(n) == 0) {
            cout << "NO\n";
            S.insert(n);
        }
        else
            cout << "YES\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Для файла можно попробовать читать до конца файла. Если в файле не 1 строка, то использовать первый метод, если же одна, то можно так:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    set <int> S;
    int n;
    ifstream i("input.txt");
    while (i >> n)
        if (S.count(n) == 0) {
            cout << "NO\n";
            S.insert(n);
        }
        else
            cout << "YES\n";
    return 0;
}
```